# MongoDB C# and how to update from Client Side using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I lovely update a document with values(Maps coord) from clienside (under privileges). MongoDB use javascript in some internals functions and for MapReduce but is not clear for me if i can use client side scripts to update my repository with values. I searching to pass values from client side to an updater Db.Repository.Updater(item). It's possible to make this using javascript or need a webservice or a rest function.

Can some expert clarify this point and suggest the way.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [http interface in mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface), so you can send direct update request to mongodb [through $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for example, or you can send ajax requests to yours handlers/pages/controllers and use mongo-csharp driver as usual for updates. Make your choise...

Include jquery at page first. In 'Update' button click handler paste code like this(to send ajax request):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "SomePage.aspx",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

In page(but it seems to me that better to use http hadlers ajax handling):

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var name = HttpContext.Current.Request["name"];
  var location = HttpContext.Current.Request["location"];
  var item = new Item(){Name = name, Location = location};
  //here update or insert your item, do what you want
  Db.Repository.Updater(item)
}
```

Comment: Um Bugai13, Can you help me litle more in the second case. I have seen Rest interfaces docs with Node and test files but it's not very clear for me. Can you submit a simple sample.tks

Comment: I don't understand what directly you want, but I a little explained secod case. Please, clarify you question if you need something else.